# C++ Data file handling

Tags: c++, file-handling

I got this code online for my school project, it works fine with turbo c++ but why i run this in visual studio enterprise 2015 and code::blocks it gives me some unknown output. I have attached the outputs, please help me out i have tried _strcmp but not solved the problem. This is the code i m trying to run in codeblocks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class crim_rec
{
    char name[20], sex[10], fathr_name[20], addrs[25], offense[20], blood[25], dob[9], reward[50];
    int crim_code;
    void disp();
public:
    void get();
    void wtf();
    void rff();
    void search();
    void del();
    void mod();
}c;
void crim_rec::get()
{
    puts("\nEnter name of criminal:");
    gets(name);
    puts("\nsex (m/f):");
    cin >> sex;
    puts("\nEnter date of birth:");
    gets(dob);
    puts("Enter blood group (Ap/An/Bp/Bn/ABp/ABn/Op/On:");
    gets(blood);
    puts("\nenter father's name:");
    gets(fathr_name);
    puts("enter address:");
    gets(addrs);
    puts("\nEnter crime commited:");
    gets(offense);
    puts("\nEnter reward on criminal:");
    gets(reward);
}
void crim_rec::disp()
{
    cout << "The record of criminal:\n";
    cout << "\nName of criminal: " << name;
    cout << "\nsex: " << sex;
    cout << "\nDOB: " << dob;
    cout << "\nBlood Group: " << blood;
    cout << "\nFather's name: " << fathr_name;
    cout << "\nAddress: " << addrs;
    cout << "\nCrime: " << offense;
    cout << "\nReward: " << reward;

}
void crim_rec::wtf()
{
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("CBI.txt", ios::app);

    get();
    ofile.write((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    ofile.close();
}
void crim_rec::rff()
{
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("CBI.txt");
    ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifile.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    while (ifile)
    {
        disp();
        ifile.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    }
    ifile.close();
}
void crim_rec::search()
{
    char m[20];
    ifstream ifile("CBI.txt");
    puts("Enter name of criminal which has to be searched");
    gets(m);
    ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifile.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    while (ifile)
    {
        if (strcmp(m, name) == 0)
            disp();
        ifile.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    }
    ifile.close();
}
void crim_rec::del()
{
    char b[20];
    ifstream ifile;
    ifile.open("CBI.txt", ios::app);
    ofstream ofile;
    ofile.open("new.txt", ios::app);
    puts("Enter the name of the criminal whose records you want to del");
    gets(b);
    ifile.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    ifile.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    while (ifile)
    {
        if (strcmp(b, name))
            ofile.write((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
        ifile.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    }
    ifile.close();
    ofile.close();
    remove("CBI.txt");
    rename("new.txt", "CBI.txt");
}
void crim_rec::mod()
{
    char d[20];
    int p;
    puts("\nEnter name of criminal whose record you want to modify\n");
    gets(d);
    fstream f;
    f.open("CBI.txt", ios::in | ios::out);
    f.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    f.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
    int a = f.tellg();
    while (!f.eof())
    {
        if (!strcmp(d, name))
        {
            puts("\nPress 1 to change name\nPress 2 to change sex\nPress 3  to change date of birth\nPress 4 to change blood group\nPress 5 to change father's name\nPress 6 to change address\nPress 7 to change crime committed\nPress 8 to change reward on criminal\n");
            cin >> p;
            switch (p)
            {
            case 1:
                gets(name);
                break;
            case 2:
                cin >> sex;
                break;
            case 3:
                gets(dob);
                break;
            case 4:
                gets(blood);
                break;
            case 5:
                gets(fathr_name);
                break;
            case 6:
                gets(addrs);
                break;
            case 7:
                gets(offense);
                break;
            case 8:
                cin >> reward;
                break;
            }
            f.seekg(a - sizeof(c), ios::beg);
            f.write((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
        }
        f.read((char*)&c, sizeof(c));
        a = f.tellg();
    }
    f.close();
}
int main()
{
    int ch;
    char choice;
    do
    {
        cout << "\t Central Bureau of Investigation";
        cout << "\n ********************************************";
        cout << "\n\n *  1. View criminal details                 *";
        cout << "\n\n *  2. Add new criminal details               *";
        cout << "\n\n *  3. Search a criminal record              *";
        cout << "\n\n *  4. Delete a criminal record              *";
        cout << "\n\n *  5. Modify a criminal record              *";
        cout << "\n ********************************************";
        cout << "\n\n Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> ch;


        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:

            c.rff();
            break;
        case 2:

            c.wtf();

            break;
        case 3:
            c.search();
            break;
        case 4:
            c.del();
            break;
        case 5:
            c.mod();
            break;
        default:
        {
            cout << "\nerror!";
        }
        break;
        }
        cout << "\ncontinue? (y/n)\n";
        cin >> choice;
    } while (choice == 'y');
    cout << "\nGood bye";
    return 0;
}
```

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSaBr.png)
[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Em0C.png)

Comment: *it works fine with turbo c++* -- Why are you using `turbo C++`?  It is 25 years old.  There is a big chance that a lot of this code will either not compile or work properly when used with a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: I have tried vs enterprise 2015 first, then tried codeblocks then on turbo c++ it works fine. I don't want to use turbo c++, even i m using it for the first time, i don't know the reason. :P

Comment: Why didn't you debug the program in VS 2015?  Also, all those compilers that it didn't work for basically are telling you that there is something wrong with your program that an old compiler didn't detect.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie, have a look on the output images that i have attached.

Comment: Everything is going good excepting name of the criminal and his/her DOB.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Thanks for making me notice that!

Comment: I just can't enter the 'name of the criminal' and 'DOB'

Comment: Please use cin>> has you do for cin>>sex, because I tried for name, i.e. cin>>name and I can enter the name normally. Also to notice that my clang++ at runtime complains about using gets because it's considered unsafe.

Comment: @fedepad, i want to enter the full name with spaces. :(

Comment: The way you enter a name with spaces is to use `std::getline(cin, yourname);`.  If that doesn't work, it means that you're messing up the input stream in some way,  If you want proof, why not [write a simple  program that shows this](http://ideone.com/npEacB).  In other words, rewrite your input routines so that they conform to modern standards and you don't have a problem.  The `gets()` was removed from the `C` standard, and probably has been removed from the C++ standard (haven't checked), but you're using it.  Get rid of it in your program.

Comment: Thanks☺ I will try it.

Comment: Well, cin.getline() and getline(cin, ) are not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?  Did you try that simple example I linked to?  Does that work?  If it does, then build on that until you see that it doesn't work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie cin.ignore() solved the problem.☺ I can use it in visual studio 15 without any error.☺☺

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be due to using puts() and gets(). They seem to leave the trailing newline character in the input. Replacing them with std::cout and std::cin respectively fixed the weird output for me (if I understood your question correctly)

Comment: Yeah, this fixed the problem, but leaves a problem too, what if the user wants to enter full name with spaces ?? then 'sex' will have the same problem of 'name of the criminal'

Comment: cin.getline(name,20) is what you are looking for, however be careful to clear the input stream whenever appropriate using cin.ignore()

Comment: I have tried cin.getline() already, not working, I mean, same output.

Comment: If you are not clearing the stream, you are bound to face the same problem while the program runs. See this for more information
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/6046/
What happens is the newline you implicitly input to the stream when hitting Enter for selecting something for the menu, gets trailed as input to the "name of criminal". getline is enough to grab both names (with the space), but keep in mind they will show up with a space in your file too.

Comment: cin.getline(name, 20) have the same output as gets(name).

Comment: cin.ignore() solved the problem. Thanks and Cheers.☺☺